# PHP form validation replay issue

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

Consider the following form containing textfield and submit button:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php isValid();?>" class="urln">
    <input name="url" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="urlField"/>
    <input name="ybutton" type="submit" value="Add!" class="logButon" action="<?php isValid();?>"/>
</form>
```

The definition of `isValid()` is as follows:

```
function isValid()
{
    $string = $_POST['url'];
    $youtubeURL = parse_url($string);
    if($youtubeURL["host"]=="www.youtube.com")
        echo 'videoAdmin.php';
    else
        echo '';
}
```

The problem is that sucessful submit of youtube urls happens on the second form submission and not after the first. The idea is to submit correct url's right after filling the form(maybe some AJAX?). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, I reread your script and now I see what it's doing.

Comment: I made the file but it ruins the $_POST super-globals after validation

Comment: you can save them in `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just easily save the POST data in the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, action attribute is intended to contain an URL to send the HTTP request. The thing you set works in the second submit because, when you load it for the first time, it has no POST to check, therefore it prints blank. Second time, is echoes the xxx.php thing. PHP is read by server and it does not perform stuff unless you reload the page changing parameters (in post, in session or something else).

To do what it looks like you need to, you have to do that check in a plain javascript function AND update the action attribute when clicking on a common button or `<a>` element if you want ( setting `onclick=validate()` ).